# Problema ao carregar URL com WebView Kotlin

Tags: html, android, kotlin, webview

Estou tentando abrir um html dentro do assets no Android Studio, porém a página fica completamente em branco.

OBS: Quando coloco qualquer link externo, ele funciona.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(com.example.myapplication0.R.layout.activity_main)


    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(com.example.myapplication0.R.id.webview)

    val webSetting = webView.settings
    webSetting.builtInZoomControls = true
    webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())

    webView.loadUrl("assets/index.html")







}
```

}

Esse é meu XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa apontar para o caminho absoluto da sua pastas assets.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(com.example.myapplication0.R.layout.activity_main)


    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(com.example.myapplication0.R.id.webview)

    val webSetting = webView.settings
    webSetting.builtInZoomControls = true
    webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewClient())

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
}
```